# Closing my application is interfering with my Form1_FormClosing event

Tags: c#, try-catch, sqlconnection, formclosing

At the form load i am trying to see if my application can connect to the database or not. If it doesn't connect i want to show a message box with a nice message, and close the application. The problem that i am having is that when the it trys to close the application it hits the Form_closing event that asks them "if they want to exit the application" it looks kind of strange for a user that does not have access to the application/database to view the message box. I just want to skip the form closing event and just close the form, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     checkcon();
  }
  private void checkcon()
  {
     try
     {
       MSSQL.SqlConnection con = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr);
       con.Open();
       con.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Your domain account does not have sufficient privilages to    continue with the application please contact the IS support Team.");              
       Close();
     }

  }

  private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit the application?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
     if (result == DialogResult.No)
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
     else
     {
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a static bool var as a check wether to show Dialogue or not:

```
 public static bool HasPermission=true;
 private void checkcon()
  {
     try
     {
       MSSQL.SqlConnection con = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr);
       con.Open();

       con.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     { 
       HasPermission=false;
       MessageBox.Show("Your domain account does not have sufficient privilages to    continue with the application please contact the IS support Team.");              
       Close();
     }

  }

 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  { if (HasPermission)
    {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit the application?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
     if (result == DialogResult.No)
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
     else
     {
     }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate it, so you are basically declaring the static bool to true, then false if it doesn't find the connection, then it hits the formclosing and that event says if its true than run that event else close is my understanding right???

Answer (score 0):

I think that is very much easy.

Just create a variable of type boolean and check if user has access to database? If not then please close it without any confirmation.

Let me explain you by modifying your code:

```
  bool userGotPermissionToYourApplication = true;

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     checkcon();
  }
  private void checkcon()
  {
     try
     {
       MSSQL.SqlConnection con = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr);
       con.Open();
       con.Close();

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Your domain account does not have sufficient privilages to    continue with the application please contact the IS support Team.");              
       userGotPermissionToYourApplication = false;
       Close();
     }

  }

  private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    if(userGotPermissionToYourApplication)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit the application?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal But apomene beat you to it and both your solutions are exactly the same and i understood the concept.